# TypeError: unsupported Python data type: numpy.ndarray line 32

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing

Trying to use MATLAB code in python, I have encountered this error.
I am basicaly trying to call MATLAB functions via the MATLAB engine for image processing.

Python code:

```py
import matlab.engine
import numpy as np
import math as m
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
eng=matlab.engine.start_matlab()
nb_classe = 50
nb_image = 12
chemin = 'C:/Users/oussa/OneDrive/Documents/MATLAB/Base/'
nb_ima_train = 6
Nb_point_LBP =8
dist_LBP = 4
type = 'u2'
attributs = np.zeros((nb_classe * nb_ima_train, 3*255 ))
num_classe = np.zeros((nb_classe * nb_image, 1))
comp_train  =  1
comptrainn = []

for i_classe in range(1,nb_classe * nb_image):
    if ((np.remainder(i_classe,2)) == False):
        num_classe[comp_train] = m.floor((i_classe-1)/nb_image)+1
        num_image = 1+np.remainder(i_classe-1,12)
        if num_image<10 :
            fichier_train = chemin + str(num_classe[comp_train])[1] + '-0' + str(num_image) + '.jpg'
        else :
           fichier_train = chemin + str(num_classe[comp_train])[1] + '-' + str(num_image) + '.jpg'
        # affichage de l'entrainement
        J = mpimg.imread(fichier_train)

        L = eng.calculeLBPCouleur(J,dist_LBP,Nb_point_LBP,type)
```

`TypeError: unsupported Python data type: numpy.ndarray`

MATLAB code:

```matlab
function J = calculeLBPCouleur(I, dist_LBP, Nb_point_LBP, type)    
    L1 = lbp(I(:, :, 1), dist_LBP, Nb_point_LBP, type);
    L2 = lbp(I(:, :, 2), dist_LBP, Nb_point_LBP, type);
    L3 = lbp(I(:, :, 3), dist_LBP, Nb_point_LBP, type);
    
    J = [L1 L2 L3];

end
```

The `lbp` function returns an array. I tried to use `Matlab.double` function to change the type of the array to double, but this one does not work either. I had another error:
[image: error with the matlab double function]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask] and [mcve]. Then, [edit] the question with the complete error (please make a meaningful title of your post and include the **complete** error, i.e. including line numbers) into the body). Also you might want to elaborate on what the code is doing and, if necessary, translate your variable names to English if that helps us to see what the code is doing.

Comment: Again, please make a relevant title and add the complete error message **in the body of the post**. Think of us volunteers to be busy colleagues, they're not going to hand-count your lines to 32 either.